# FancyBox (Rails) Image Gallery Does Not Show Next/Previous Partial in Iterated Collection of Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox, iteration, partial-views

Tried a bunch of things and can't seem to get the next/previous partial for an iterated collection of images to show on click.

I have a collection of images that I'm iterating over; for every image, I have a fancybox link to a partial in which I pass information to the rendered partial. It's the same partial template used for every iterated image, and the only thing that changes is the image/user passed through to the partial.

I have tried putting the same fancybox grouping class as well as "rel" attribute on every item in the iterated collection but nothing seems to get me to the next/previous partial displaying with different image/info in the iterated collection. All of these fancyboxes render the correct partial with correct information on a stand alone basis (meaning, if I put a bunch of images on an index page and click on each image separately to the fancybox, all the correct information shows up....it's really only going next/previous that doesn't work).

Here's my code for the iteration:

```
 <% current_user.portfolio_images.each do |portfolio_image| %>


   <%= link_to "#picture#{portfolio_image.id}", {:class => "grouped-pictures", :rel => "gallery-images"} do %>
     <%= image_tag(portfolio_image.upload_image.url, :data => {:original_height => "#{portfolio_image.original_height}", :original_width => "#{ portfolio_image.original_width}"}) %>

   <div style="display:none;">
     <div id="picture<%=portfolio_image.id%>">
       <%= render "shared/picture_view", :portfolio_image => portfolio_image, :user => portfolio_image.user%>
     </div>
   </div>

   <% end %>


<% end %>
```

Comment: In case anyone was wondering-- figured out a solution. Just end the link_to block before you start the div (display:none), so your link_to block is effectively only around the partial. Works fine now. Very weird before that it would have even made a difference but it did.